# Computation time of a Binom matlab (or C) routine

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, numerical-algorithms

I am trying to write a Matlab (or C) routine for the exact probability F of observing K or more successes when a success probability P is expected ($\sum_{k=i}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$).
I am trying to figure out the following:

> 1. I need to know, if it shoud work for large numbers:
>      i.e. K=501000, N=10^6, P=0.5
> 2. Is there a way to calculate how long the computation takes?

Maybe it is possible to perform a computer routine that calculates an approximation? Like Poisson Probability

Comment: Whether it should work for large numbers is up to you.

Comment: Programming is offtopic here. I expect that part of your question might be better served on [scicomp.SE] or [SO].

Comment: Instead of writing your own routine, I suggest looking for a library in which such a routine is already implemented.

Answer (score 2):

If you can avoid it, you don't want to compute sums like that at all.

1. If you compute terms like $p^k$ directly, you'll get big errors due to floating-point precision (because your result will be almost zero).

   If you haven't seen it, one common way to handle small probabilities is to apply the logarithm trick:

   $\qquad \displaystyle p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\ \leadsto\ k \cdot \log p + (n-k) \cdot \log(1-p)$.
2. If possible, apply well-known closed forms for sums to eliminate them entirely. Computing *that* is less problematic, both in terms of numerical issues and running time.
3. Failing that, find an approximation that you can tune to the required precision.

And also:

- Computing running times with an algorithm is not computable in general. You will have to apply algorithm analysis yourself. After implementing an actual algorithm, that is. See a good textbook or our [reference questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/844#844) for starters.

Comment: Is there a closed form for that sum? I wasn't aware of one (only bounds on it and approximations).

Comment: @D.W.  If memory serves, the sum starting from $k=0$ is $1$. It may be possible to find a nice closed form for the sum from $k=1$ to $i-1$, but I haven't checked.

Comment: Yes, for the special case of summing over $k=0..n$, of course the answer is 1 (probabilities sum to 1).  However for the general case of summing over $i..n$, I don't believe there are any closed forms -- at least, none known to me.  So, I'm confused by your suggestion to use well-known closed forms, and I'm wondering if you can either elaborate on that -- or if perhaps you might want to delete that suggestion.

Comment: @D.W.  Better now? (I really don't know if/how this specific sum can be simplified; it looked attackable.)